# ViewController segues to MapViewContoller: MapView region wrong first time opened

Tags: mkmapview, segue

Good evening,
I'm having problems with an app where a MapView is loaded when a User pushs the Bar Button on a ViewController. The MapViewController gets loaded and the Map shows correct annotations (not shown in source), but the startregion is wrong the first time the App is started and the MapView is opened. When I push the Back button once and reopen the MapView the startregion is fine. It just doesn't work for the first time.

the log gives me the correct values loaded from the plist:
47.572132 and 7.579397

Since I started coding objective-c two weeks ago, please keep your answers as simple as possible ;-)

**h.File:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "Annotation.h"


@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet MKMapView *singlemapview;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *data;
@property int selectedBuilding;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *location;
@property float longitude;
@property float latitude;
@end
```

**m.File:**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()
@end

@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize data;
@synthesize selectedBuilding;
@synthesize location, latitude, longitude;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDictionary *dataItem = [data objectAtIndex:selectedBuilding];

    latitude = [[dataItem objectForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue];
    longitude = [[dataItem objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];

    NSLog (@"%f",latitude);
    NSLog (@"%f",longitude);

    MKCoordinateRegion startregion = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0} };
    startregion.center.latitude = latitude;
    startregion.center.longitude = longitude;
    startregion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
    startregion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;

    [singlemapview setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite];
    [singlemapview setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [singlemapview setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [singlemapview addAnnotation:singlebuilding];
    [singlemapview setRegion:startregion];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

My app had exactly the same behavior when calling setRegion method in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. but, calling it in viewDidAppear corrected the problem. hope this helps.

Comment: I'm now using viewDidAppear but this doesn't solve the problem. I can either set [singlemapView setRegion:startregion animated:YES] which will show the whole earth at zero.zero coordiante and zoom in to my region or i can set [singlemapView setRegion:startregion animated:NO]. then the region will be shown but before there will be the view on earth again for probably 0.2 seconds. any idea to solve this?

Comment: You might want to add an explicit pause period like 0.2 secs before trying to display your map. I'm sure it's related the delay before initializing the mapkit instance. you can try something like this-> dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self displayMyMapOnTheViewController];
    });

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem now through using the `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` function instead of using `-(void)viewDidLoad`

As i understand now:

- `ViewDidLoad` is called once before a new view is opened (before the segue animation starts). But it is however still too late to draw the map correctly.
- `ViewDidAppear` is called every time after a view did appear on the screen (after the segue animation is over).
- `ViewWillApper` is called and calculated totally before a new view is opened (before segue animation). That's why it works properly when you have a map.